# How to create a static enum with a value that has a hyphen symbol in Java?

Tags: java, enums

how to create the static enum like below

```
static enum Test{
    employee-id,
    employeeCode
}
```

As of now, I am getting errors.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is not possible with Java, because each item has to be a valid identifier (and valid Java identifiers may not contain dashes).

The closest thing would be adding a custom property to each enum value or override the `toString` method, so you can do the following:

```
Test.EMPLOYEE_ID.getRealName();    // Returns "employee-id"
Test.EMPLOYEE_CODE.getRealName();  // Returns "employeeCode"

public enum Test
    EMPLOYEE_ID("employee-id"),
    EMPLOYEE_CODE("employeeCode");

    private Test(String realName) {
        this.realName = realName;
    }
    public String getRealName() {
        return realName;
    }
    private final String realName;
}
```

Comment: And use all-caps for enum constants.

Comment: You should make realName final.

Answer (score 19):

This is not specific to enums. This applies to all identifiers in Java: class names, method names, variable names, etcetera. Hyphens are simply not allowed. You can find all valid characters in [Java Language Specification, chapter 3.8 "Identifiers"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8).

To illustrate the problem:

```
int num-ber = 5;
int num = 4;
int ber = 3;

System.out.println(num-ber);
```

What would you expect to happen here?

Answer (score 2):

You can not do this. Enum constants must be legal Java identifiers. Legal Java identifiers can not contain `-`. You can use `_` if that's an acceptable substitute.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare the enum constant with a hyphen. 
If you hyphen to be retrieved as the value of the enum, you should have a value method in enum which you either use in its toString method or access this method on the enum to get the hyphen value