# Java - create enums with dot notation

Tags: java, identifier, enumerators

I need to have enums with dot notation like this WEATHER.SUNNY since they represent topics using wildcards. I know that this is not possible because enums need to be valid identifiers.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493002/how-to-create-a-static-enum-with-a-value-that-has-a-hyphen-symbol-in-java) someone suggest to overwrite the toString method but I dont really get how that is meant. 
However, is it still possible to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can definitely do what @Stefan suggests, but this might be a good use case for attaching a field to your enum values:

```
public enum Topic {
    SUNNY("WEATHER.SUNNY"), CLOUDY("WEATHER.CLOUD"), ...

    String notation;

    Topic(String notation) {
        this.notation = notation;
    }

    public String getNotation() { return notation; }
}
```

And then you can invoke `Topic.SUNNY.getNotation()`.

Comment: Thanks for this appraoch its working fine. I am not really sure how to apply this to more complex structures though. Imagine something like: WEATHER.SUMMER.SUNNY.DRYHUMIDITY

Comment: Is there an implied hierarchy there? Will every object have 1 of each of those category of thing? Should they be different enums as fields of one Topic class? Could you store a Set<Topic>? Sorta depends on what you're going for?

Comment: sorry I was unprecize. The dot indeed implies hierarchical order and will lead to a tree structure. Doing this with Strings was obviously no porblem, but again with enums, I do not really know how to achieve a more complex structure.

Comment: So you could invest a lot and write a DSL (e.g., https://dzone.com/articles/creating-internal-dsls-java), or you could just do a builder pattern where your build() method does some validation on which enums you've picked in your various fields. If you want to be able to do the thing you reference here (WEATHER.SUMMER.SUNNY.DRYHUMIDITY), you could nest inner enums, but the underlying code would get messy fast.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with defining enum that has a capitalized name.
It would be not consistent with Java naming conventions, but it works.

```
enum WEATHER {
    SUNNY, CLOUDY;
}
```

Then you would use like this:

```
WEATHER weather = WEATHER.SUNNY
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample code that shows the idea of overriding toString:

```
public class Test {

enum Weather { Sunny, Cloudy;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "WEATHER." + super.toString().toUpperCase();
    }

};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Weather.Sunny);
}
}
```

Output: `WEATHER.SUNNY`